# tkinter bindtags escalar evento

Tags: tkinter, binding

Quiero escalar un evento, en este caso click izquierdo.
Quiero que cuando se "clickee" dentro del área interior, verde, se ejecute el evento del área interior y del área exterior.

[image]

Cuando todo el código está en una misma clase, lo tengo resuelto (siguiendo un ejemplo), **pero no comprendido :-(**. Está explicitado en las sentencias, comentadas, bindtags.

No se como extrapolar esa lógica / esas sentencias al caso de estar implementado en distintas clases, como en el ejemplo que sigue.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        super().__init__()   
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Fuera.TFrame', background='Yellow')

        fuera = ttk.Frame(parent, style='Fuera.TFrame', height= 100, width=100)

        Dentro(fuera)

        fuera.bind('<Button-1>', self.fueraClick)
        fuera.pack(expand=1)

        # bindtags = list(dentro.bindtags())
        # bindtags.insert(1, fuera)
        # dentro.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))

    def fueraClick(self, event):
        print("Click en zona exterior")

class Dentro(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__()
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Dentro.TFrame', background='Green')
        dentro = ttk.Frame(master, style='Dentro.TFrame', height= 50, width=50)
        dentro.bind('<Button-1>', self.dentroClick)
        dentro.pack(padx=30, pady=30)

    def dentroClick(self, event):
        print("Click en zona interior")

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

He entendido que los binds se guardan a nivel global y hay algún modo de manipularlos, pero como he indicado no he comprendido la lógica. Una explicación, para torpes, de la filosofia de implementación y un ejemplo que lo aclarase, me ayudarían mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El sistema de bindings de Tkinter se basa en las llamadas "bindtags" o etiquetas de enlace. A pesar de los años que tiene Tk/TCL y de que es en gran medida el inspirador conceptual de gran parte de los frameworks modernos que han copiado o perfeccionado los conceptos que Tk introdujo, su sistema de bindings sigue siendo posiblemente uno, si no el más, flexible y potente de todos.

Cuando se enlaza un widget con un evento, lo que realmente se asocia no es el widget en si, siempre es una etiqueta.

Cada widget tiene por defecto cuatro etiquetas asociadas, aunque puede tener más, menos o ninguna. Cuando se detecta un evento en un widget se comprueba cada etiqueta  para ver si hay un enlace para ese evento, de encontrarlo se ejecuta la callback asociada al enlace y se pasa a la siguiente etiqueta del widget, así hasta recorrer la lista de etiquetas al completo o si una de las callback retorna  "break", lo cual rompe la propagación del evento por la lista de etiquetas.

La lista por defecto de etiquetas es:

1. **El widget mismo**    -> `widget.bind` enlaza de forma predeterminada a ésta etiqueta
2. **La clase del widget**  -> `widget.bind_class` enlaza de forma predeterminada a ésta etiqueta
3. **Ventana raiz**
4. **`"all"`**                -> `widget.bind_all` enlaza de forma predeterminada a ésta etiqueta (enlaze global)

y son comprobadas en ese orden. Parece simple, pero el potencial es enorme. Por ejemplo, en los widgets `Entry`, cuando se pulsa una tecla, el evento llega primero al tag del widget mismo como cabe esperar,
pero el carácter no se inserta en éste punto, eso lo hace el binding asociado a la etiqueta de la clase. Si nos interponemos en éste punto podemos manejar el evento e impedir o permitir que algo se
inserte en el widget independientemente de que la tecla se pulsara, éste es el mecanismo que hay detrás de la validación de los entries, que son procesados a nivel del tag del widget. De ésta forma, si el carácter no se valida se rompe el evento y no llega a la clase, evitando que el carácter se llegue siquiera a ingresar en el Entry.

Además podemos agregar nuestros propios tags y colocarlos en la posición que nos interese para que sean procesados antes o después según nos convenga.

Si observamos la lista de bindtags por defecto, no hay ninguna que apunte al widget padre y es que en Tkinter los eventos no se propagan al widget padre, por lo general, a excepción de un puñado de casos que generalmente involucran a widgets base como la misma `tkinter.Tk` o `tkinter.Toplevel`. Que no se propague al padre por defecto no significa que no se pueda hacer, la flexibilidad de las etiquetas de enlace llega al rescate de nuevo, podemos enlazar enventos con otros widgets que ni siquiera tiene que ser padres directos de un widget dado, basta con insertar la etiqueta asociada a dicho widgets en la lista de bindtags del widget que primero recibe el evento y éste  "se propagará" a donde nos de la gana y a cuantos widgets queramos.

En tu caso, el principal error es que tratas de modificar las bindtags del widget equivocado. Cuando se hace click en el frame interior, es éste widget el que recibe el evento y por tanto son sus bindtags las que se procesan. Es en la lista de bindtags del widget hijo en la que tienes que insertar la bindtag del padre:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Example:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Fuera.TFrame', background='Yellow')
        fuera = ttk.Frame(parent, style='Fuera.TFrame', height= 100, width=100)
        Dentro(fuera)
        fuera.bind('<Button-1>', self.fuera_click)
        fuera.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def fuera_click(self, event):
        print(f'Click en zona exterior\n{"-" * 22}')

class Dentro:
    def __init__(self, master):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Dentro.TFrame', background='Green')
        dentro = ttk.Frame(
            master, style='Dentro.TFrame', height= 100, width=100
            )
        dentro.pack(expand=True)

        bindtags = list(dentro.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(1, master)
        #                  ^^^^^^---> Referencia al frame padre "fuera"
        dentro.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        dentro.bind('<Button-1>', self.dentro_click)

    def dentro_click(self, event):
        print("Click en zona interior")


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("375x250")
    Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observa que si quisieras que la callback del padre se llame antes que la del hijo, basta con alterar el orden de las bindtags:

```
bindtags.insert(0, master)
```

simple, pero con una flexibilidad enorme, porque además, éste segundo widget puede mediante sus bindtags propagar el evento a otros o cortarlo retornando `"break"` en cualquier momento.

---

En respuesta a los comentarios

### Un ejemplo enlazando el evento también en root

```
import time

def measure_time(function, vect):
    t_accum = 0
    repeticiones = 0

    while t_accum < 0.5 : 
        copia = vect.copy()
        t1 = time.process_time()
        function(copia)
        t2 = time.process_time()
        t_accum += t2 - t1 
        repeticiones += 1

    tiempo_promedio = t_accum / repeticiones
    return tiempo_promedio
```

### El uso de `bind_all`

La aplicación de `bind_all` es cuando queremos enlazar eventos globales, es decir, queremos que algo pase sin importar el widget de la aplicación que reciba el evento. Cun caso típico puede ser el típico menu emergente  al hacer click derecho presente en muchas apps.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent,  *args, **kwargs)   
        tk.Label(
            self, text="Hola StackOverflow.es", bg='#b6f0e7'
            ).pack(expand=True,  fill="both", side="top")
        frame = tk.Frame(self, bg="black")
        frame.pack(expand=True,  fill="both",  side="bottom")
        tk.Button(frame, text="No hago nada").pack(expand=True,  fill="x")
        self._popup_menu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0) 
        self._popup_menu.add_command(label="Hola...") 
        self.bind_all("<Button-3>", self.do_popup) 

    def do_popup(self,event): 
        try: 
            self._popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root) 
        finally: 
            self._popup_menu.grab_release() 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500') 
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Creo que cojo la idea global. Hay o puede haber una serie de acciones por defecto que se mantienen en una lista de tags asociadas al widget. Estas acciones pueden ser remplazadas por nuestras decisiones, **via bind y/o bind_class**, aunque existe la posibilidad de que no sean reemplazadas sino añadidas  **(opcion "+")** en la llamada.

Existe también la posibilidad de modificar la secuencia de ejecución de esas acciones según en mecanismo que has expuesto, modificando en orden de la lista de tags.

Comment: En el ejemplo, se modifica insertando el "tag" del padre. En mi problema práctico, el widget a actuar está varios niveles por encima. ¿Existe algún truco de progamación para hacer llegar al widget inferior la referencia del superior manteniendo la flexibilidad, es decir no **master.master. ... master**?.

¿Ese truco, valdría también para el caso de ramas laterales?

Comment: Personalmente, aunque no es elegante ni recomendado, he intentado, para otra situación, pasar la referencia de una frame entre widgets alejados, via una variable global, pero no he sido capaz. La variable recibia el valor, pero en el widget receptor
siempre recibo None [No he investigado el porque a fondo :-(],

Comment: He intentado hacer una prueba para comprobar el tercer caso, root, He hecho el root.bind. pero no he sido capaz de que me reconozca la función llamada. Me da el error **NameError: name 'root_click' is not defined**

Comment: Finalmente, abusando, En el cuarto caso, **all**, ¿Algún ejemplo funcional en el que se pueda aplicar?

Comment: Me autocontesto a mi última pregunta sobre una posible funcionalidad para bind_all. En el siguiente enlace 
[Python tkinter binding mousewheel to scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355902/python-tkinter-binding-mousewheel-to-scrollbar)
sugieren la asociación del evento "<mouseweel>" a todos los widgets para asociar la rueda del ratón al movimiento de los deslizadores ("scrolles"). Después hay una idea mejor, pero en principio podría ser una solución

Comment: Hola @Chemag, he editado la pregunta agregando dos ejemplos sobre lo comentado de root y bind_all. La tercera duda no la he tocado, da para una respuesta en si misma y aunque relacionada es una pregunta diferente, de hecho podemos tener muchas más razones para necesitar una referencia a otro widget que el procesado de eventos.

Comment: Tengo una respuesta preparada, si quieres formularla adelante. Así mismo puedes autocontestarte con la respuesta que has agregado a ésta pregunta, que es una de las posibilidades y es correcta (yo en mi respuesta en principio no a incluiría por si quieres agregarla). Eso si, te recomiendo eliminar la respuesta de aquí ya que no responde directamente a la pregunta y por tanto técnicamente no cumple con las normas del sitio. Saludos.

Comment: He lanzado la pregunta. Espero que bien. Gracias por tus sugerencias