# Tkinter Paso de información y/o referencias entre widgets alejados

Tags: tkinter

Como parte de la tercera pregunta de la referencia [tkinter bindtags escalar evento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/361639/tkinter-bindtags-escalar-evento/361921?noredirect=1#comment651357_361921)
se me ocurrió el siguiente código, que me parece correcto, como un modo de pasar la información de la ventana que posee la función que se desea ejecutar (equivalente al escalar) es pasando esa información a través de las llamadas a los sucesivos widgets hasta el que debe "escalar". En el ejemplo se hace vía el parámetro "callbackwin".

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Example:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Fuera.TFrame', background='Yellow')
        fuera = ttk.Frame(parent, style='Fuera.TFrame', height= 300, width=300)
        Dentro1(fuera, callbackwin = fuera)
        fuera.bind('<Button-1>', self.fuera_click)
        fuera.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)

    def fuera_click(self, event):
        print(f'Click en zona amarilla (exterior)\n{"-" * 22}')

class Dentro1:
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        callbackwin = kwargs.pop("callbackwin", None)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Dentro1.TFrame', background='Green')
        dentro = ttk.Frame(
            master, style='Dentro1.TFrame', height= 150, width=150
            )
        Dentro2(dentro, callbackwin = callbackwin)

        dentro.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=30, pady=30, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        bindtags = list(dentro.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(1, master)
        #                  ^^^^^^---> Referencia al frame padre "fuera"
        callback = master

        dentro.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        dentro.bind('<Button-1>', self.dentro_click)

    def dentro_click(self, event):
        print("Click en zona verde")

class Dentro2:
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        callbackwin = kwargs.pop("callbackwin", None)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Dentro2.TFrame', background='Red')
        dentro = ttk.Frame(
            master, style='Dentro2.TFrame', height= 60, width=60
            )

        Dentro3(dentro, callbackwin = callbackwin)

        dentro.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=30, pady=30, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        bindtags = list(dentro.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(1, master)
        #                  ^^^^^^---> Referencia al frame padre "fuera"
        dentro.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        dentro.bind('<Button-1>', self.dentro_click)

    def dentro_click(self, event):
        print("Click en zona rojo")

class Dentro3:
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        callbackwin = kwargs.pop("callbackwin", None)
        style = ttk.Style()
        style.configure('Dentro3.TFrame', background='Blue')
        dentro = ttk.Frame(
            master, style='Dentro3.TFrame', height= 50, width=50
            )

        dentro.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH,padx=30, pady=30, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

        bindtags = list(dentro.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(1, master)
        #                  ^^^^^^---> Referencia al frame padre "fuera"
        if callbackwin : bindtags.insert(2, callbackwin)
        dentro.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        dentro.bind('<Button-1>', self.dentro_click)

    def dentro_click(self, event):
        print("Click en zona azul")


if __name__ == '__main__':    
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("375x250")
    Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

En este caso se necesitan datos del la instancia de widget Dentro1 en la operación desde el widget Dentro3, para poder ejecutar el bind **Button-1** de Dentro1 cuando se ejecute este evento en Dentro3, frame azul.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A alguién se le ocurre un modo alternativo y mas limpio de conseguir lo mismo?

Comment: si estas usando un esquema de mvc puedes parametrizar todas las entradas, entonces seria tipo capturar en una vista, y ese dato mandarlo como parámetro a la vista necesario

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Comment: @Ruslan López Edito y concreto el problema